# Comparing strings with if else

Tags: c

I want to make a program that has a key to open. But when i comparing the key and the input, it always says "Wrong":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char key[5]="april",ckey[5];
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    scanf("%s",ckey);
    if(ckey==key){
        printf("Correct.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Wrong.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible to solve the problem without using other libraries?

Comment: Write your own version of `strcmp`

Comment: Your strings are overflowing the arrays.

Comment: A string in C requires a terminating null. So if the string has 5 characters you need at least 6 `char` locations to hold it.

Comment: don't modify deeply your question! You changed `if (ckey == key)` into `if (!strcmp(ckey, key))` which makes some comments/answers strange…

Comment: By the way appart for the arrays `key` and `ckey` that are too small for their content the current code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

you have to check character by character.
try this code :

```
    int main(){
    int i = 0 ; int j = 1;
    char key[6]="april",ckey[6];
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    scanf("%s",ckey);
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++){
      if(ckey[i] != key[i])
            j=0;
    }
    if(j == 1)
        printf(%s,"Correct.");
    else
        printf(%s,"Wrong.");  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char key[5] = "april"` overflows the `key` buffer.

Comment: yep you're right. he needs to declare key as an string of 6 characters.

Comment: Making the arrays large enough is actually a good idea. Still, a finite buffer is per se not large enough for unbounded input, and you didn't correct that.

Answer (score 2):

You have to leave space before "%s" inside the `scanf` statement,so that the '\n character is not stored in `ckey` to ensure success of comparison.note: `ckey` must have size 6 or more.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    char key[] = "april",ckey[6];
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    scanf(" %5s",ckey);
    if(!strcmp(ckey, key)){
        printf("Correct.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Wrong.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change the scanf to restrict length of string entered

Comment: A space in the pattern would be superfluous. Making the arrays large enough though is actually a good idea. Still, a finite buffer is per se not large enough for unbounded input, and you didn't correct that.

Comment: rolled back the question, please take a look.

Comment: @Deduplicator i am away from home and laptop with my horendous android phone am afraid i cant edit and do much. :D .

Answer (score 1):

You make several mistakes in array sizing for your keys. Remember, a C string is always terminated by a nul character and you must account for this when you size your arrays to accept such strings.

scanf is unsafe, don't use it. Use fgets instead. A safe use of fgets is:

```
fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
```

The answer to your question is no, it would be better to use strcmp if you want to lexically compare strings in C and that would involve including the  header. But even so, this is not adding any other "libraries" since fgets and strcmp are in the same standard C library.

If you must not add any other headers (which makes no sense if this is part of a larger project but makes perfect sense if this is a homework problem) then you can write your own strcmp (we'll call it compare here) and call it from main.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int compare (const char* src, const char* dst)
{
    int ret = 0;
    while( ! (ret = *src - *dst) && *dst){
        ++src, ++dst;
    }
    if ( ret < 0 )
        ret = -1 ;
    else if ( ret > 0 )
        ret = 1 ;
    return( ret );
}

    int main(void){
    char key[6]="april",ckey[6];
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    fgets(ckey, sizeof ckey, stdin);

    if(!compare(key,ckey)) {
        printf("Correct.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Wrong.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A better use of your time would be to write it using the functions available to you in the standard C library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void){
    char key[6]="april",ckey[6];
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    fgets(ckey, sizeof ckey, stdin);

    if(!strcmp(key,ckey)) {
        printf("Correct.");
    }
    else {
        printf("Wrong.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But even this solution has a flaw. It will accept "aprilaaaa" or any string beginning with "april" as a valid ckey. Can you explain why? How would you fix this?

Answer (score -6):

In the condition of the if statement

```
if(ckey==key){
```

there are compared two addresses of the memory areas occupied by the arrays.

So you will always get false because the arrays occupy different memory areas.

If you may not use other standard functions as for example `strncmp` or `memcmp` declared in header `<string.h>` then you can write the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void ){
    char key[5]="april",ckey[6];
    printf("Enter the key: ");
    scanf("%5s",ckey);

    size_t i = 0;

    while ( i < sizeof( key ) && key[i] == ckey[i] ) ++i;

    if( i == sizeof( key ) ){
        printf("Correct.");
    }
    else{
        printf("Wrong.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Instead of `scanf` it would be better to use `fgets`. In this case the size of the array `ckey` must be increased.

This declaration

```
char key[5]="april";
```

is totally valid in C though is not valid in C++.:)

Comment: I thought `"april"` was 6 bytes, so assigning it to a `char key[5]`, which is allocated on the stack, would overflow and write a `'\0'` somewhere, or not?

Comment: @Siguza First of all the answer is totally correct. As for your question then the compiler uses the string literal to initialize the array. It will use characters of the string literal that correspond to elements of the array. The string literal either is stored separatly in the static storage duration or even is not stored and used only for the initialization. I wrote in my post that it is correct initialization in C.

Comment: The code you are showing in your answer says "correct" if the user types, "aprilx" at the "Enter the key:" prompt.

Comment: @lurker You can not enter more than 5 characters. See the array declaration and the function scanf.

Comment: The OP didn't say there is any restriction on the length of string the user might enter.

Comment: @lurker It is very interesting!:) Now try to explain for yourself how it can enter a string that is greater than the array used to store the string without arising undefined behaviour of the program.

Comment: @lurker I showed in my answer how correctly to enter a string in the declared array. Any other questions?